# Calculator algorithm

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to create a calculator that can peform simpel operations and you should be able to have several values and different operators. It's not done yet so it will be improved later on but right now I have problem with the method that performs the calculation.

Before I post the relevant code. The other part is just Swing object instantiation.

```
    private class OperatorListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()== resetButton){
            Operators.clear();
            Numbers.clear();
            actualNumber.setText("");
            previousNumbers.setText("");
        } else if(e.getSource() == sumButton){
            Numbers.add(new Double(actualNumber.getText()));
            Double Result = performCalculation(Numbers, Operators);
            actualNumber.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
            previousNumbers.setText("");
        } else if(e.getSource() == sqrtButton){

        } else {
            /*
             * The operator numbers handlers. When a operator
             * button is clicked the number in the lower JTF
             * is parsed to Double value and added to Numbers
             * list. Operator added to Operators list. Lower
             * JTF is cleared.*/
            Numbers.add(new Double(actualNumber.getText()));
            Operators.add(e.getActionCommand());
            String currentPriovusNumbers = previousNumbers.getText();
            previousNumbers.setText(currentPriovusNumbers + " " + actualNumber.getText() + " " + e.getActionCommand());
            actualNumber.setText("");
        }
    }
}

    private double performCalculation(ArrayList<Double> Numbers, ArrayList<String> Operators){
    double result = Numbers.get(0);
    for(int index = 0; index < Numbers.size(); index++){
        switch(Operators.get(index)){
            case "+":
                result += Numbers.get(index + 1);
                break;
            case "-":
                result -= Numbers.get(index + 1);
                break;
            case "/":
                result /= Numbers.get(index + 1);
                break;
            case "*":
                result *= Numbers.get(index + 1);
                break;
            case "%":
                result %= Numbers.get(index + 1);
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at com.calculatorSwing.business.Calculator.performCalculation(Calculator.java:146)
at com.calculatorSwing.business.Calculator.access$6(Calculator.java:143)
```

Line 146 is the first switch case statement which lets me know that there is no such index that I try to access but I've checked the Operators list and there is a "+" inside element 0. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `for` loop of `performCalculation` method.

**From:**

```
 for(int index = 1; index <= Numbers.size(); index++)
```

**To:**

```
for(int index = 1; index < Numbers.size(); index++)
```

According to your for `loop` following `ArrayList` get will be Exception.

```
Numbers.get(Numbers.size());// will generate IndexOutOfBoundsException.
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve it be adding Numbers.size() - 1 as for-loop condition.

Comment: Are you forgetting Java index's start at 0 and not 1?

Comment: @StuWhyte Probably you did not notice `double result = Numbers.get(0);` before for loop.

Comment: @Masud Ahh I didn't. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you pass List with only one element

Then `Numbers.size()` will return `1`, the condition  `index <= Numbers.size()` will be evaluated to `true` as is `index` is initialized with `1`.

And in consequence you will get `Numbers.get(1)`. And this will raise `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for empty or array with one element.

Solution is to not use `<=` but only `<` in for condition.

EDIT:

The computation method `performCalculation` is to complex do perform to many operation with no control.

You should first validate the input.

- Check that list have proper size and react to that.

Case1: When the number list is empty, what would happen ? 
Case2: When the operator list is empty what would happen ? 
Case3: When number has one value and operator is empty ? 
etc.

This is the first stage. When when you are sure what to perform you can perform as expected.

You must set a bag of rules that must be completed for your algorithm to work properly. Any exception of that rule must be covered by additional code. Only valid input will work there for you must assure that you provide it.

Try to write more method to separate the logic then you will find the gaps you miss now.

Comment: The thing is that I initialize the double variable to the first elemnt in Numbers and I want to perform operation on that variable so having used the first element I have to add a + 1 to the index to e.g. add the next double to result. I've changed the performCalculation method.

Comment: The problem is that your logic for calculation is to complex. You should try to separate it in atomic methods.